# Ubuntu Network manager

Tags: gnome, network-manager

I uninstalled network-manager from my Ubuntu-gnome, so I don't have internet connection. How can I reistall it.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have NM but you have network card.
First

`ifconfig`

to see interface name. To setup `eth0` card use this command

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
```

after that add default gw

```
sudo route add default gw yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Try now to install NM with `software manager`
Also you can configure network card with editing `/etc/network/interfaces`

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
        gateway vvv.vvv.vvv.vvv
```

Configure dns `/etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Manually restart your network interface with the new settings:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: The sequence would be a bit different if the interface is wireless. Is it wireless @dinymate ?

Comment: Not correct, @2707974 If it is wireless, he must declare the SSID and encryption key.

Comment: You are right. Manual for cli configuration of wlan is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your network using the following command:

```
sudo ifconfig <Interface_name> <IP_address> netmask <Netmask> broadcast <Broadcast_IP>
```

For example:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

To set up the gateway:

```
sudo route add default gw <IP_of_gateway>
```

for example:

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

After that your network should be Up although you need DNS to access sites via hostnames:

```
printf "\nnameserver <DNS_IP>" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

For example:

```
printf "\nnameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Note that all these changes are temporary, you can now install network-manager and start setting up the network permanently. Actually you don't need `network-manager` at all to save your network configurations, you can use [save the contents in `/etc/network/interfaces`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic) file to be read by `ifupdown` upon boot so the network will be configured properly.

If you want to install `NetworkManager` after setting up the network, run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: -1 op said - I don't have Internet connection, apt requires Internet connection

Comment: @markkirby: Actually i was on my way editing it....

Comment: Ok I will be happy to change the vote

Comment: @markkirby: check the edits

Answer (score 0):

You can find the package here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/network-manager

It is source only though so you need to build it you self

Please see the following link on building from source as it is too much to copy here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo